# Error by creating file

Tags: php, file, fatal-error

I got a error when creating a file using this php code:

```
$userdbfile = file('userfiles/' . $steamprofile['steamid'] . '.txt');
$fhuserdb = fopen($userdbfile, 'a');
fwrite($fhuserdb, $steamprofile['steamid']);
fwrite($fhuserdb, "0");
close($fhuserdb);
header("Location: index.html");
exit;
```

Error:

> Warning: file(userfiles/76561198043436466.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u294343259/public_html/admin/lw/login.php on line 7 
>   Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/u294343259/public_html/admin/lw/login.php on line 12
>   Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u294343259/public_html/admin/lw/login.php on line 13
>   Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u294343259/public_html/admin/lw/login.php on line 14
>   Fatal error: Call to undefined function close() in /home/u294343259/public_html/admin/lw/login.php on line 15

Comment: Better to use use `file_put_contents` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php ... *nix permissions permitting and all the other usual provisos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) doesn't create a new file! It only reads file. So just remove it and use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), like this

```
$userdbfile = 'userfiles/' . $steamprofile['steamid'] . '.txt';
$fhuserdb = fopen($userdbfile, 'a');

//checks that the file was successfully opened 
if($fhuserdb) {
    fwrite($fhuserdb, $steamprofile['steamid']);
    fwrite($fhuserdb, "0");
    fclose($fhuserdb);
}
//^ The function is 'fclose()' not 'close()' to close your file
header("Location: index.html");
exit;
```

- Also make sure that the folder does have proper permissions to write to it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual:

- [the `file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads an entire file into an array. The first warning tells you the requested file *does not exist*
- [the `fopen` function](http://php.net/fopen) expects the first argument to be a string, `file` returns an array or `false` on failure. The first argument of `fopen` should be a string, specifying a path to a file you want to open. It returns a resource (file handle) or `false` on failure
- [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite) expects you to pass a *valid* file handle, you don't check the return value of `fopen` (which is `false` in your case), so you're not writing to an actual file
- `close` does not exist, [`fclose` does](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php), again: this needs to be called on a *valid* file handle, which you don't have, and thus this line, too, will fail
- [the `header` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) can only be called if no output has been sent (read the bit below *description* carefully), your code is generating warnings and errors, which produce output. therefore, it's too late to call `header`

So what now?

Pas the path you're passing to `file` to `fopen`, check its return value and proceed accordingly:

```
$userdbfile = 'userfiles/' . $steamprofile['steamid'] . '.txt';
$fh = fopen($userdbfile, 'a');
if (!$fh)
{//file could not be opened/created, handle error here
    exit();
}
fwrite($fh, $steamprofile['steamid']);
fwrite($fh, '0');
fclose($fh);
header('Location: index.html');
exit();
```

Comment: Very nice list, shows exactly what every function does! (good catch with the header())